# Auto page break while creating PDF in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, tppdf

I have to create a PDF which contains data like a quotation document (text, tables, images, etc.). The data varies from 1 page to 3-4 pages. A table cell may have combination of text and images. Also, I have custom graphics to be rendered in PDF to show different shapes.

Example format:
[image]

I have tried `PDFKit` provided by Apple. I was able to draw individual parts. But I don't know how can I achieve auto page break mode (which shifts data to new page when there is no more space available in a page). One way to achieve this is that I have to calculate individual heights and divide data into pages as per available page size.

Is there any better way to do it using `PDFKit`?

I am also aware about creating PDF using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData()`. It also doesn't support auto page break. We have to call `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo()` for each new page.

I have also tried [TPPDF](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF) and [SimplePDF](https://github.com/nRewik/SimplePDF). Both don't support either page break on table or custom views.

I also can't go for **HTML to PDF** solution as I have custom views to be drawn in PDF.

Which is the best way in iOS to create PDF with above mentioned requirements?

Comment: Hi there, I am the creator of TPPDF. Sorry I didn't see your question earlier. Please checkout the `develop` branch over on GitHub and open up an issue if the new table logic/rendering does not fulfill your use case

Answer (score 0):

"One way to achieve this is that I have to calculate individual heights and divide data into pages as per available page size." - this is the only way as PDFKit does not include automatic data layout and auto page breaks.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Apple needs to introduce this functionality as it is available in SDKs like iText PDF.